# permutation and combinations discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

In combination and permutation what should I do if he says repetition "allowed" && order doesn't matter or anything with the same meaning.
I am thinking of multiply it by a number to remove the repetition possibilities but I can't seem to get it right.
example we have 7 men and 4 women in how many ways can they acquire three jobs knowing that one person can take more than one task (order doesn't matter)

edited the mistake my bad

Comment: Give an example.  "Repetition 'not allowed'" will have different meanings in different contexts.  *What* cannot be repeated?  Repetition of elements?  Repetition of sets?  Repetition of methods?  Repetition of....?

Comment: Who is "he" in "he says"?  Shouldn't you have a question mark at the end of a question?  What do you mean by "multiply *it*"?  What is "it"?

Answer (score 1):

There exist well known formulas for repetition and non-repetition for combination and permutation. Then you need to analyze the question and depending in the presented case (ordering, repetitions, length) choose one of these formulas:

Combination without repetition of $n$ elements taken $k$ by $k$. Order doesn't matter, so $abc$ is the same as $cba$: $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Combination with repetition of $n$ elements taken $k$ by $k$ where elements can be repeated once or more. Order doesn't matter ($abc=cba$) and you can also have $aab$, $aaa$ etc: $$\binom{n+k-1}{k} = \frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!((n+k-1)-k)!}
=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-1)!}$$

Variation without repetition of $n$ elements taken $k$ by $k$. This is a permuted combination, so ordering does matter ($abc\neq cba$ both are different):

$$V_{n,k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

Variation with repetition of $n$ elements taken $k$ by $k$. This is the same as a variation but with the condition that elements can be repeated:

$$V_{R_{n,k}} = n^k$$

Permutation without repetition of $n$ elements. Here we have $n=k$ so the length of the arrangements is equal to the amount of elements: $$P_n=n!$$

Permutation with repetition of $n$ elements with $a,b,c\cdots k$ elements repeated: $$P_{n_{,a,b\cdots k}} = \frac{n!}{a!b!c!\cdots k!}$$

Comment: thank you very much I edited the question to be precise

Comment: I will edit my answer so you can know where ordering matters and when not, then surely you can find out which case (Formula) to choose.